# ShareThis Buttons Alignment

Tags: alignment, sharethis

I am trying to to align all the buttons FB Like, tweet, G+ on the same line. But it looks Misaligned.

Trying to add CSS properties doesn't help because it uses an i-frame.

http://mink7.com/projects/startupradar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I inspect in Safari's inspector I can see that the line-height applied to #mainBody and #contentHeader is 80px, and is being resolved as the line-height for these elements, too.  See the last inspector block in the first screenshot, below.

Changing this value to 0px makes them line up, albeit a little too high.  You'll have to play with your CSS to get things where you want them, but it's a clue anyway...

Before:

[image: before version]

After:

[image]

Hope it helps!